# Handling IDisposable object without the using statement

Tags: c#, idisposable, using-statement

I'm sure this is an easy question, but what am I supposed to do when handling an `IDisposable` object without the using statement?

Comment: yourObject.Dispose(); <-- Just add that before leaving the method you're working in.

Comment: Probably because it's a question that is answered by reading the first result when Googling 'c# using'

Comment: _what am I supposed to do when ..._ - add a `using(){}` statement?  The question isn't very clear or complete. Please elaborate on the what and why.

Comment: Welcome recent user to SO.  What research have you done?  What have you tried?

Comment: Searched both google and stackoverflow about this _specific_ question, I decided to ask question here to have a little bit more support, having found anything. Clearly I haven't got how to ask questions here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the `using` construct does is call on `Dispose()` which `IDisposable` mandates you implement.

So you can just call it yourself, instead of:

```
using (IDisposable something = new SomeDisposableClass()) {
    ...
}
```

Do:

```
IDisposable something = new SomeDisposableClass();

try {
   ...
} finally {    
   something?.Dispose();
}
```

Notice the use of the `try..finally` which will ensure `Dispose()` is called even if there is an exception.

Comment: Your 2nd sample is not exception-safe.